# PyTorch matrix multiplication does not respect slicing

Tags: python, pytorch, precision, huggingface-transformers, torch

I got to this by having to batch long inputs for transfomer models, noticing difference between batched and non-batched results. I finally isolated the first discrepancy I noticed, resulting in the following:

```
import torch

n = 20

vec = torch.rand(n, 20)
a = torch.rand(30, 20)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(i, torch.equal(
        torch.nn.functional.linear(vec, a)[:i],
        torch.nn.functional.linear(vec[:i], a)))
```

yielding the output:

```
1 False
2 False
3 False
4 True
5 True
6 True
7 False
8 False
9 False
10 True
11 True
12 True
13 False
14 False
15 False
16 True
17 True
18 True
19 True
20 True
```

This is just one operation, when combined multiple times (as in a transformer), it might cause large divergence, enlarging the atol for which torch.allclose outputs True. Why is that, and can one do something about it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this (on CPU) getting only True values.

Comment: Also maybe related: [torch's matrix multiplication precision](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_float32_matmul_precision.html). There is an optional tradeoff between precision and speed.

Comment: @Daraan Thanks! What torch version do you use? I use 1.13.1+cu117 (but the code as above is ran on CPU, like you say, so the cu117 part should not be relevant), I run this on Linux (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS).

Comment: @Daraan and regarding your link, I checked now and I have torch.get_float32_matmul_precision() == 'highest', so it is not the problem I guess (the strange "every 3" pattern in my output also hints that it is not a simple precision matter, but some optimization that the matrix multiplication does based on the size)...

Comment: I just tested it with your version. So torch 1.12.1 produces only True. Switching to 1.13.1 reproduces your result in the same pattern. Torch 2.0.1 Outputs False only for the first the rest are True again.

Comment: Pytorch does optimized computations (maybe SIMD?) when the batch size is 1. For almost all models, the inference results for the same input are different for batch sizes 1 and 2. This is the reason why it is False when i == 1. For i >= 2, I don't know why. However, I think pytorch does some optimization here as well, since I reimplemented this calculation in numpy and could not reproduce the error.

Comment: I was able to reproduce a similar thing in `2.0.1+cpu` by swapping `20` and `30` in your code. I.e., `vec = torch.rand(30, 30); a = torch.rand(20, 30)`. The interesting part is, it yields `True` where `i >= 20`. And if I change it to `a = torch.rand(25, 30)`, then it yields `True` where `i >= 25`. So, at least for `2.0.1`, it seems that pytorch changes how they compute when `input.shape[0] < weight.shape[0]`. However, this is not the same for larger shapes.

Comment: @ken Interesting (and confusing), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the brave world of floating point arithmetic! `float` operations introduces rounding errors, and matrix multiplications accumulate them to significant values.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/numerical_accuracy.html
If you avoid inprecise rounding with

```
vec = torch.floor (torch.rand(n, 20)*10)
a = torch.floor( torch.rand(30, 20)*10 )
```

you'l get all `True`-s.

Possible solution is to use `torch.isclose`.

---

DEL

Comment: Hi, thanks. Not sure if your answer is super-relevant to the precise question at hand, which is more delicate, I believe. I am talking about "batch" calculations (I think of vec as a batch of n smaller tensors vec[i]) and in principle, ideally, the calculation should be completely the same whether I perform it at once or per-batch element. And we see here a very strange pattern of False/True depending on the number of batch elements, which probably is related to some strange optimization talking place under the hood...

Comment: Calculations are the same, but their order is possibly not, and it is matters. `floats` brake associativity law.

Comment: there is no interaction between the calculations for vec[i] for different i, so the order should not matter.

Comment: Firstly, for `n>0` `vec[:i]` is still matrix. Secondly, even multiplying vector by matrix, there is scalar product inside, and it's computation order is on machine's choice.

Comment: if you see what are the computations involved, then say, it is, simplifying, like computing ab and ac for three floats a, b and c. The order should not matter, and ideally the result should be deterministic if a, b and c are deterministic. However, here we see (roughly), that asking the computer to calculate (ab, ac) at once and extracting the resulting ab (first coordinate) gives a different answer than asking it to compute ab alone.